# Syntax for typecasting a pointer in C

Tags: c

I came across a code segment where a fix has been added for removing the compiler warnings.

Before:

```
int test;
SYSTEM_START_Function(0, &test);
```

After:

```
int test;
SYSTEM_START_Function(0, &(char)test);
```

with:

```
static void SYSTEM_START_Function (UInt8 parameterSize, char* pointerToPassedParameters)
{
}
```

Can anyone tell me is it the right syntax?. If yes, please explain how it will be interpreted by the compiler.

Comment: Read the C11 standard [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf).

Comment: please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733960/pointer-address-type-casting

Comment: If `parameterSize` is zero, it seems likely that `pointerToPassedParameters` is unused (intuitively at least; the designer could of course have simply used perverse and misleading parameter names!).. In that case you could just pass NULL and avoid compiler warnings and unnecessary casting.

Comment: Not clear what your problem is. If you don't understand what a typecast is, see the standard or your prefered C book, even online this has been answered a thousand times,  It looks like bad style, but as this is no standard function, nor `main`, the semantics are unclear. If you Read The Fine Manual and are still clueless, you should ask the author/vendor.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pointer/address type casting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733960/pointer-address-type-casting)

Answer (score 1):

Since `test` is an `int`, `&test` is a pointer to an `int`. The function you are calling expects a pointer to a `char` in its second argument.

The C operator for converting a thing of one type to a thing of another type is a cast operator. It has the form `(` *type-name* `)` *expression*.

The type name of a pointer to `char` is `char *`. To take the address of `test` and convert it to a pointer to `char`, you write:

```
(char *) &test
```

This particular conversion is supported in C, subject to various caveats that the software you are working with has presumably accounted for. (It is not unusual for system functions to treat arbitrary objects as sequences of bytes.) However, you should be aware that not all pointer conversions are proper C. Before converting to types that are pointers other than pointers to character objects, you should learn C’s rules about pointer conversions.